# How to solve error operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'string'

Tags: c#

How to solve error

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'string'

```
textBox5.Text = (float.Parse(textBox3.Text) - float.Parse(textBox4.Text).ToString());
```

Comment: Paste the code instead of an image.

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post an screen shot image of your code and error instead of the actual text.

Comment: `float.Parse(…).ToString()` converts the converted float directly back into a string. You need to place the parenthesis, so the `ToString()` call happens on the result of the subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are converting your operand to a string before applying the subtraction operation.

Try the following instead:

```
textBox5.Text = (float.Parse(textBox3.Text) - float.Parse(textBox4.Text)).ToString();
```

Going further, you should code against user input. I would suggest using `float.TryParse` instead of parsing directly and using the result in an operation.

```
float val1, val2;
if(!float.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out val1)) val1 = 0;
if(!float.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out val2)) val2 = 0;
textBox5.Text = (val1 - val2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

move the .ToString() to the end of the line, just after the closing bracket.